# How can I run a search in my postgress database, return the result and then send it to be displayed on an ejs page?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am using Node.js w/ Heroku & Postgres
My code needs to pull data from Postgres, store that data, send that data to a webpage to be displayed.

The code looks like this. I want to get the information from
`SELECT * FROM people;`, then I want to store it somehow, and then I want to `res.render` it onto 'pages/sql'.
So when I visit myURL.com/sql I will see a stringified version of the results gotten from the database. So far I can see this information in my console when I run `heroku logs --tail` but I want it to be rendered on a live webpage visible to anybody.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do a lot more than this, but this would help for now.

By wanting to do much more I'd like to eventually find out how to have a full ejs webpage and to pull in a large amount of data from the db onto one page and not use res.render just for one table.

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
});
app.get('/sql',function(req,res){ 
  res.status(200);
  client.connect();
  client.query('SELECT * FROM people;', (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let row of res.rows) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    }
    client.end();
  })
  res.render('pages/sql', {body:"HELLO"});
});
```

Ideally where it says HELLO, I would be sending the data I get from the stringified JSON

Answer (score 0):

So you have to send the response when you got the result, so you should do something like this

```
 app.get('/sql',function(req,res){ 
   res.status(200);
   client.connect();
   client.query('SELECT * FROM people;', (err, res) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     for (let row of res.rows) {
       // If you want to get the single row
       res.render('pages/sql',JSON.stringify(row));
       console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
     }
     // if you want all rows return then
     res.render('pages/sql',JSON.stringify(res.rows));
   client.end();
   })
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I've tried this however the `client.end();` is closing the db before I can actually get any data from it. I need to now find a way to keep the db open, grab the data and then close the db without it ending before that data is grabbed